# I'm getting an error processing the following JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm getting a feed from the web and I need to process it, however I'm getting an error and not sure how to process a list inside a list. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking.

The JSON file is like this

```
     {"alerts":[{"country":"AS","nThumbsUp":0,"city":"Albion, Vic","reportRating":3,"confidence":0,"reliability":5,"type":"JAM","uuid":"19c56810-3b8b-31a1-a658-c779f99b9388","magvar":279,"subtype":"JAM_STAND_STILL_TRAFFIC","street":"Polish Club Driveway","location":{"x":144.807815,"y":-37.771797},"pubMillis":1559688120073},{"country":"AS","nThumbsUp":0,"city":"Calder Park","reportRating":2,"confidence":0,"reliability":5,"type":"WEATHERHAZARD","uuid":"283a1bb4-6c0e-3f84-a4ff-cf187aa97dbd","roadType":2,"magvar":221,"subtype":"HAZARD_ON_SHOULDER_CAR_STOPPED","street":"Calder Park Dr","location":{"x":144.761619,"y":-37.679113},"pubMillis":1559689265092},

url = urllib.request.urlopen(turl)
output = url.read().decode('utf-8')
raw_api_dict = json.loads(output)

for x in json.loads(output)['alerts']:
    print(x['country'])
    print(x['nThumbsUp'])
    print(x['reportRating'])
    print(x['confidence'])
    print(x['reliability'])
    print(x['type'])
    print(x['uuid'])
    print(x['roadType'])
    print(x['magvar'])
    print(x['subtype'])
    print(x['street'])
    print(x['location_x'])
    print(x['location_y'])
    print(x['pubMillis'])
```

***This is the error **
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "waze.py", line 58, in 
    print(x['location_x'][0])
    KeyError: 'location_x'

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly because the JSON which you are using is invalid. Use the below JSON.

```
{
"country": "AS",
"nThumbsUp": 0,
"city": "Taylors Hill",
"reportRating": 1,
"confidence": 0,
"reliability": 5,
"type": "JAM",
"uuid": "a0241505-b0f8-3e83-a9c9-678f3c9039c5",
"roadType": 2,
"magvar": 103,
"subtype": "JAM_STAND_STILL_TRAFFIC",
"street": "Taylors Rd",
"location_x": 144.764866,
"location_y": -37.725576,
"pubMillis": 1559626611999 }
```

Python compiler considers  **'** as a special character.

> use [JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON always before running in code.  I hope my answer helps.  See the above comment.  I guess json.dumps() could help you in this case.

Comment: I understand your point. The easy solution is post-processing your feed's data from single quotes to double.  The other one could be defining your custom JSON parser.

Comment: could you try json.dumps() to parse the JSON. I have attached an example below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

person_dict = {'name': 'Bob',
'age': 12,
'children': None
}
person_json = json.dumps(person_dict)

# Output: {"name": "Bob", "age": 12, "children": null}
print(person_json)

person_dict = json.loads(person_json)

print( person_dict)

print(person_dict['age'])
```

use json.dumps to solve the problem if it works.

Comment: That outputs " like you said.
{"name": "Bob", "age": 12, "children": null}

Comment: See the updated code I have attached. You can redo a JSON mapping for accessing your individual object using json.loads()

Comment: url = urllib.request.urlopen(turl)
    output = url.read().decode('utf-8')
    raw_api_dict = json.dumps(output)
    myjson = json.loads(raw_api_dict)

    print(myjson)
    print(myjson["alerts"]) 
    TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I couldn't understand much from the comment. Please edit your question if its a different issue.